# How to access an Vue component within another component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using the single file components, but I can't access a component via another component, follow what I've tried...

```html
<template>
  <div id="containerPrincipal" @click.stop="teste">
 ...
<template>

<script>
 /*Other component*/
 import flex_div from './elementos/Div.vue'

 export default {
  name: 'containerPrincipal',
  methods : {
   teste () {
      componente = new flex_div().$mount();
      console.log(componente);
   }
  },
  components: {
   flex_div
  }
 }
</script>
```

Error

> _Div2.default is not a constructor

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is an application where everything will be generated dynamically, so I need to communicate several components between SI, is it possible?

Comment: It's not clear to me what SI is, but typically you would not manually create components in this fashion.If it's a user interface element, you could include it in the template and conditionally render it. If not, I wouldn't use a component.

Comment: @Bert, it worked! I'm going to answer the question for future references, pardon me for not explaining, I don't speak English.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve I had to instantiate the Vue again and reference the component...

```
<template>
  <div id="containerPrincipal" @click.stop="teste">
 ...
<template>

<script>
 /*Other component*/
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import flex_div from './elementos/Div.vue'

 let flexdiv = Vue.component('divFlex', flex_div);

 export default {
  name: 'containerPrincipal',
  methods : {
   teste () {
      let componente = new flexdiv().$mount();
      console.log(componente);
   }
  },
  components: {
   flexdiv 
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but isn't this what you want to do?

```
<template><
  <div id="containerPrincipal" @click.stop="teste">
    <flex-div ref="flex_div"></flex-div>
  </div>
<template>

<script>
 /*Other component*/
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import flexdiv from './elementos/Div.vue'

 export default {
  name: 'containerPrincipal',
  methods : {
   teste () {
      let componente = this.$refs.flex_div
      console.log(componente);
   }
  },
  components: {
   flexdiv 
  }
 }
</script>
```